# Proper usage of OOP PHP

Tags: php, oop

I am new to the OOP world I have been reading as much as I can about it and have never been more confused. I understand that its great for organizing code and making it more maintainable, etc. I have written some OOP code but I am unsure if its proper, it works fine though.

I am confused about `public` `private` functions along with `extends` and `constructors`. I haven't used them yet in my code and do not see where I would use them in a real life example. The more I read and try to understand it the more confused I get. I have included my code and was wondering if someone could point out mistakes, improvements, proper usage, organization. I feel it would help me better understand if someone with a lot of experience was to look at my code  and give me pointers.

```
class userFunctions{

    const SALT_LENGTH = 9;

    //Retrieves encrypted password from database returns in variable $salt
    public function retrievePassword($conn,$username) {
    try{
       $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE `userName`= :userName');
       $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $username);
       $stmt->execute();
       $salt = $stmt->fetchColumn();

    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
        return $salt;
}
    //End of retrieve password method




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    //Generate an encrypted password method
    public function generateHash($password, $salt = null)

{
    if ($salt === null) {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, self::SALT_LENGTH);
    } else {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
        return $salt . sha1($salt . $password);
}
    //End of generate encrypted password method




////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////



    //Check database for duplicate username
    public function userCheck($conn,$userName){
    try{
        $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE `userName` LIKE CONCAT("%",:userName)');
        $stmt->bindValue(':userName', $userName);
        $stmt->execute();
        $count = $stmt->fetchColumn();
        return $count;
    } catch (PDOException $e){
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();

    }

    }
    //End of Check databade for duplicate username



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




    //Add user to database
    public function Register($conn,$userName,$encryptedPass){

    try{      
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO users (userName, password) VALUES (:userName, :password)');
    $stmt->execute(array(':userName' => strip_tags($userName), ':password' => $encryptedPass));
    }  catch (PDOException $e){
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
        //End of add user to database



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31520

Comment: I added it there after the recommendation in the first comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Public and Private
    When you are writing a class, there are certain methods for which you would like to be callable (object.method), and others that are not going to be called outside the class. For example in your password checking class, it would make sense to have a method such that a user name and password were passed in and that method checked the password, if that method used another method to encrypt this password before sending it to the database to check that the encrypted password matched the one on the database, it would not make sense to have this password encryption method as public, as only the class is going to use this method, and nothing else needs to.

Comment: In PHP, it's `$object->method` (arrow, not dot operator)

Comment: @Phil I am used to C#, but the concepts are the same.

Answer (score 1):

If a function or variable is `public` then it can be accessed outside of the class. If it is `protected`, it can be used in that class and extended classes. If it is `private`, it can only be used in that class.

The `__construct()` function of a class is what happens when you use `new Class()`. You can pass variables into the class with that function, too.

```
class Class{
    public $var;
    public function __construct($passedin){
        $this->var = $passedin;
    }
}
```

With this you could have:

```
$class = new Class('This is the passed in variable, that will be stored in $var');
```

If you have a main class for a store or something, you might want to extend the class and include a seperate class for the product type.

```
class Food extends Product{
    //Stuff that food would have that clothes wouldn't have
}
```

You can also watch these videos [here](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL5C5262980C9247B4) that phpacademy has made that are tutorials for OOP and explain a lot of things. I have never done OOP myself, but I have watched the tutorials and that is where I have learned all of these things.

Comment: FYI - You forgot `public function` before `__construct`

Comment: And to be able to pass the variables in when using `new Class()` the `__construct` function needs to be `public`, so, like @Phil said, `public function __construct()`